# Is there a way for Azure DevOps Code Review to not immediately post comments?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When making a review in Azure DevOps on a pull request is there a way to get it so comments aren't immediately posted to the pull request? It's really annoying having comments go out one at a time and I want to send all of my review when I finish my review.

Comment: That would be a really nice feature, actually.  As far as I know, it doesn't exist.  I had a junior developer get rather annoyed (rightly so!) when he got 60 emails from me (via ADO PR comments) one evening! ;)

Comment: Bummer! It's available in most other modern code review systems I think (such as gerrit, etc) Is there a place for feature requests for azure so I can make a suggestion?

Comment: Also, can you group the emails so you get them in batches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make the comments and send the notification all at one time.

All you need to do is **Do Not** click **Comment** button when you finish a comment. Leave the comment box **Unsaved** and move on making other comments.

When you finish all the comments, Click the **3dots** on the top right corner and Click **Save all comments**. Then the notification emails will be sent out all at one time.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I'll try this out and accept it if it works. Thank you! Not very intuitive design.

Comment: Hi @AzureDude  How did it go?

Comment: To follow up - when you do this with many comments it crashes the page.

Comment: But afterwards it seems like sometimes it does save them.

Comment: I would hesitate doing this with > 60 comments.

Comment: What happens if I write 60 comments and the tab crashes? Are these "drafts" saved at all or do I just lose all of the comments?

Comment: @chillNZ it appears that they're lost. "Save all comments" is far inferior to the similar Gitlab feature, where comments can be saved as you work, at the end of which there's a button to submit all comments. The Azure Devops way isn't nowhere near as good.